# I have written this query in SAS but it is selecting more records than expected

Tags: sql, sas

```
proc sql;
  create table test_Check10 as
  select
    a.KRI_RK,SCORE,
    KRI_ID,
    b.KRI_TEMPLATE_RK,
    KRI_TEMPLATE_ID,
    d.KRI_RSPNS_SCL_RK,
    RANGE_MID_2,
    RANGE_MAX
  from 
    Sasoprsk.Kri_Obs_l as a,
    Sasoprsk.Kri_l as b,
    Sasoprsk.Kri_template_l as c,
    Sasoprsk.Kri_rspns_scl_l as d    
  where 
    a.KRI_RK=b.KRI_TEMPLATE_RK and 
    b.KRI_ID=c.KRI_TEMPLATE_ID
  order by 
    SCORE
  ;
quit;

proc sql;
  create table final as
  select * from test_Check10
  where
    SCORE <= RANGE_MAX and SCORE >= RANGE_MID_2
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: if you can add an sample data, someone can help you easily

Comment: Are you getting the expected number of records in `test_Check10`, before the last `proc sql`? Are the variables being tested in the last `proc sql` all numeric?

Answer (score 0):

The actual source data may not be meeting your minds presumed data model.

The case of 'extra rows' is often due to an insufficiently constrained join, which can be based on repeated rows with respect to the join key fields.  What this means is that there may not be 1-1, or presumed 1-N, concurrence in the data with respect to

```
a.KRI_RK=b.KRI_TEMPLATE_RK and 
b.KRI_ID=c.KRI_TEMPLATE_ID
```

Look for replicates in the result set and use the join key field values to closely examine the corresponding records in source data tables.  You may have to

- add more constraints to the join expression
- include additional tables in the join
- cogitate over a long walk or a couple beers

Comment: Thanks i have done from other method now if i have got all scores which are between the range and now if data is updated i want to get the score which are new entered by not showing the previous one now which approach I should use?

Comment: Do some thinking/research first, write some code and ask  a *new* question if you get errors or unexpected results.  Good answers, 'they will come', if you Include sample data that demonstrates the scenario.